# Odoo 14 Domain, self.env.user.id in Many2many field

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I use Odoo 14 CE

how to check if the id of the current user is in a many2many field

I want to make a document visible only for the user that their id

something like this:

```
responsible _ids = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='res.users', string='responsible')

[self.env.user.id,'in',' responsible _ids ']
```

but this is not working for me

can you help me, please

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're just writing it the wrong way, Odoo needs as a left operand in a domain a string, always. So they do support the other way around with the "in" operator:

`('responsible_ids', 'in', [self.env.user.id])`

Should do the trick :)

If not, don't hesitate to contact me back

Answer (score 0):

To display the [Time Off](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/hr_holidays/views/hr_views.xml#L195) button on the employee form, Odoo uses a [computed field (Boolean)](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/hr_holidays/models/hr_employee.py#L38) because field names or python expressions can't be used as values in `attrs` domain

You can define a boolean computed field and set its value to `True` when the current user is a responsible and `False` otherwize then use to display document

```py
show_document = fields.Boolean(compute='_compute_show_document')

def _compute_show_document(self):
    for rec in self:
        rec.show_document = self.env.user in rec.responsible_ids
```

Define `attrs` like following:

```
<field name="document" attrs="{'invisible': [('show_document', '=', False)]}" />
```